How to push the actual .git folder into a GitHub repository
Today I'm facing an issue that you may help me with, related to Git Bash.
I have a few folders for which I created a specific online repository (for each one) to store my work online. When working with git, a .git folder is created within the working folder to store the actual data (different commits, etc.).
When pushing everything online, I notice this .git folder doesn't come along with the rest. I would like this folder to be also stored in the repository. This way, when I clone back my repository onto my desktop, I also get the git data (previous commits, etc.). Is that possible ? Does it even make sense ? What is your workflow regarding this? My final intent is to have no working folder on my desktop (to not have plenty) and downloading the one I'm working on only when required.

What makes you think if you clone the repo it wouldn't have the history?!

"I would like this folder to be also stored in the repository"- the .git directory is the repository. By analogy: what you're asking is akin to trying to store a car inside its own trunk/boot.

@jonrsharpe The fact that I don't have the history when using git bash on the folder I cloned.

@user24642980 Did you ever do git push $remote originally?

The .git folder is where git stores its stuff. (It is the repo, all the files, history, internal stuff, etc.). You don't need to worry about it.
If everything in your "working directory" is pushed to the remote, then you can delete your "working directory" (including the .git) and whenever you clone your git repo, everything gets put back (including the .git).

with exceptions: git stashes, local git config, untracked files, and dangling commits. I'm sympathetic to the OP because git arguably should have a simple way to push all of those (except maybe dangling commits) to a remote - especially local stashes.

I undetstand that point. What makes me ask the question is, if I create an empty folder onto my desk top & use git bash on that folder, then use 'git close {repository link}, I indeed get the files, but git log will not be happy, and If i use "git init" it starts a .git directory from scratch. So there is something I'm doing wrong, and I would like to know what.

Not sure what you mean by "use git bash on a folder".? git init creates a new repo - with a new .git directory, that's what it does. Maybe you can describe in more detail what you are doing.

@user24642980 did you cd your-clone before running git log? You must navigate to your cloned repo first

@user24642980 Aaaand here we found the solution to my problem. I might need to increase the coffee per hour rate on friday mornings.. :)
